# Can not invoke the knockout custom binding valueaccessor function without parameter

Tags: knockout.js

In my knockout init function for a custom bindinghandler I get this valueAccessor:

```
self.userSelectPerson = function(person) {
  self.userHasSelectedPerson(true);
  self.selectPerson(person);
};
```

Here I am in the init function:

```
'init': function (element, valueAccessor) {
 var value = valueAccessor();
```

When I do now: value(); to invoke the userSelectPerson function its missing the parameter person (I guess...) and I also get with value() an 'undefined' message in the console output.

How do I have to solve this? Or how can I invoke the function without parameter?

Comment: We need more context. Show your viewmodel binding and your html. What exactly are you trying to pass in? What is your custom binding trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

`userSelectPerson` must be an observable, in your case `valueAccessor` returns function if your custom binding points to `userSelectPerson`.

Please post sample model, HTML binding and binding code, so that we don't have to make assumptions.